# g:if inside g:link does not work

Tags: grails, syntax, gsp, taglib

The question title is enough to explain excepting the attempts that i try :

## Attempt1 :

```
<g:link controller="staff" action="all" <g:if test="${actionName=='all' }">class="active"</g:if> >Overview</g:link>
```

## Error Message

> **Error 500**
>
> **Class** :org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException
>   **Message** Grails tag [g:link] was not closed

---

## Attempt2 :

```
<g:link controller="staff" action="all" class="<g:if test="${actionName=='all' }">active</g:if>" >Overview</g:link>
```

## Error Message

> Error 500
>   **Class** org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException
>   **Message** Attribute value must be quoted (controller="staff" action="all" class="

## How to do a branching to decide if an element has css class X or not ?

X(in this example)= active

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think It will be sufficient if you will use ternary operator e.g:

```
<g:link controller="staff" action="all"  class="${actionName == 'all' ? 'active' : ''}">
    Overview
</g:link>
```

Comment: جزاك الله خيرا يا عبد الله ، أخوك من تونس